# How can I get my Django admin styles to load?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I'm using Django 1.8 with static files and also using django-offsite-storage.

When I browse the Django admin in my browser on my local machine it's requesting the CSS file `/admin/css/base.css` from my S3 bucket but without the hashed version.  I want it to use the hashed file name version because that's what get's uploaded to the S3 bucket.

I've tried switching DEBUG = True or False, but neither do the trick.

How can I get it to do this on my local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason my admin styles weren't loading was because I had DEBUG = True in a different settings file than my main settings file (which had DEBUG = False).